# Geometric PMF and the variance

Tags: probability

I am stuck on the answer for this question:
X is a geometric random variable, with var(X) = 6.

a) The conditional variance var(X-4 | X>4)? ans = 6.

b) Var(X-8 | X>4)? ans = 6.

I know that the variance for a geometric distribution is $ \frac {1-p}{p^2}$, but I can't seem to relate the formula to the answer above. So I think there maybe some additional formulas or principles related to conditional variance that I miss.

Can someone explain the reasoning for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason: The Geometric Distribution is memoryless.  $$\mathsf P(X=x\mid X>4)=\mathsf P(X=x-4)~\mathbf 1_{x>4}$$

Therefore the conditional distribution of $(X-4)$ given $(X>4)$ is the same as the distribution for $X$ ; geometric with variance $6$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about it being memoryless? Perhaps a numeric example or so? Appreciate your help though!

Comment: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X=x\mid X>4)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X=x)~\mathbf 1_{x>4}}{\mathsf P(X>4)}\\&=\dfrac{(1-p)^{x-1}~p~\mathbf 1_{x>4}}{(1-p)^4}\\&=(1-p)^{(x-4)-1}~p~\mathbf 1_{x>4}\\&=\mathsf P(X=x-4)~\mathbf 1_{x>4}\end{align}$$

Comment: sorry to ask this dumb question, but how do I interpret the $1_x>4$ at the end of the sentences? Thanks so much again!

Comment: @speedy_catch $\mathbf 1_{x>4}$ is an [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).